# Hi, im new in android dev and have questions about implementation of button onclick in viewpager2

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager2

In my app, i used viewpager2 where user can swipe and answer questions by clicking button yes/no similar like quizzes. I've tried to set the button onclicklistener where the button on the current page should change color (yes=green,no=red) when clicked. The problem is when i click the button sometimes it will change color and sometimes it's not. When it's not, buttons in back pages also will be affected even though it's not clicked yet. How to make sure only the button in current page will change color when clicked? Is the implementation of button onclick is wrong in my code or what? Ive checked the logcat and there is no error shown.

Here is my MyViewPagerAdapter.java

```
    public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewPagerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

Context context;

int[][] question_matrix = new int[][]{
        //Visual motor
        {R.string.q1,R.string.q1m},
        {R.string.q2,R.string.q2m},
        //Fine motor
        {R.string.q3,R.string.q3m},
        {R.string.q4,R.string.q4m},
        {R.string.q5,R.string.q5m},
        {R.string.q6,R.string.q6m},
        //body posture
        {R.string.q7,R.string.q7m},
        {R.string.q8,R.string.q8m},
        {R.string.q9,R.string.q9m},
        //shoulder stability
        {R.string.q10,R.string.q10m},
        {R.string.q11,R.string.q11m},
        {R.string.q12,R.string.q12m},
        {R.string.q13,R.string.q13m},
        //spatial perception
        {R.string.q14,R.string.q14m},
        {R.string.q15,R.string.q15m},
        //cross mid-line
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q16,R.string.q16m},
        {R.string.q17,R.string.q17m},
        {R.string.q18,R.string.q18m},
        //visual skill
        {R.string.q19,R.string.q19m},
        {R.string.q20,R.string.q20m},

};

public MyViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}



@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_page,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position)  {

    holder.eQuestion.setText(question_matrix[position][0]);
    holder.mQuestion.setText(question_matrix[position][1]);
    holder.yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.yes.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            holder.no.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }
    });
    holder.no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.yes.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            holder.no.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return question_matrix.length;
}



public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    TextView eQuestion,mQuestion;
    ConstraintLayout container;
    Button yes,no;
    ImageView img;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_desc);
        eQuestion = itemView.findViewById(R.id.eQuestion);
        mQuestion = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mQuestion);
        container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        yes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.yesBtn);
        no = itemView.findViewById(R.id.noBtn);


    }


}


   }
```

Here is my item_page.xml which is the layout for this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_desc"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_q1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.152" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eQuestion"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/image_desc"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:text="question"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_desc"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.108" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mQuestion"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/eQuestion"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:text="translation"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#3A3939"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eQuestion"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.061" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/noBtn"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="No"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.004"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mQuestion"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.69" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/yesBtn"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:text="Yes"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mQuestion"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.69" />
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I found the answer. It's quite easy actually. Like @mostafa3dmax said. I have to set the default color in `onBindViewHolder`. For the button color to not reset after changing pages, i just have to set

> viewPager2.setOffScreenPageLimit(int value)

As stated in documentation:

> Pages within limit pages away from the current page are created and
> added to the view hierarchy, even though they are not visible on the
> screen. Pages outside this limit will be removed from the view
> hierarchy, but the ViewHolders will be recycled as usual by
> RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make sure only the button in current page will change color when clicked

Because ViewPager2 reuses the layouts when you changed the color of a button in the next page the color of button is the last color that you set. So in the `onBindViewHolder` you must change the button's color to default :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position)  {

    …
    holder.yes.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    holder.yes.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    
    …

}
```

If you just what to change clicked button color when it clicked you can use a `StateListDrawable` as it's background

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/yourPressedColor" />
  <item  android:color="@color/yourNormalColor" />
</selector>
```

Comment: if i set the default value in onBindViewHolder, when user swipe from back to the front page it will turn back to default. I would like for the button color to stay as it is after clicked. How can i get this?

Comment: I've tried to set the default color in onBindViewHolder and use [stateRestorationPolicy](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy) but it doesn't work. The color will still change to default if turn to previous page.